# UIImageView attach in Uitableviewcell for even row only

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

i create uitableview custom cell with uiimage i want add one image only for even row but its doesnt work here are the codes

```
     UITableViewCell *cell;
        UILabel *label = nil;

        cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
    //label information
    }
       NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


     UIView *selectionView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        [selectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1]];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionView;


    if (indexPath.row % 2==0) {

            UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(128,5, 32, 32)];
            imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"England.png"];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:img];
            [imv release];

        }
        else {

           //  ....

        }
 return cell;
```

after row 3 all the rows takes this image for all row if i try to scrolling all row have one image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cells are being reused and the UIImageView is not being removed when a cell is reused. In the else statement, you need to add code to remove the UIImageView with the image. Right now, it looks like you are not keeping a reference to the UIImageView so you can't just call `removeFromSuperview`. In the else statement, you could try enumerating through all of the subviews of `cell.contentView` and removing any UIImageView:

```
for (UIView *theSubview in [cell.contentView subviews])
{
    if(theSubview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class])
    {
        [theSubview removeFromSuperview];
    }
 }
```

Note that I have not tested this code.